# What type of attack is this by adding /127.0.0.1/ in the URI request?

Tags: security, apache-http-server, logging

I am hosting a website and I see a lot of request that include **/127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1/** in the URI. Some times the **/127.0.0.1/** is present multiple of time in the URI e.g **/any/path//127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1/index.html**

What is this type of attack?

Does any one know?

Thank you.

Comment: Please, [read this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback) about that issue, also, google a bit, before asking a question

Comment: My guess would be it's a problem with a script (for example:  a .php file) that's trying to reach a url that has a typo in it.

I would try clicking around in your website and monitoring the log to see if you can produce the same output with normal surfing

Comment: @Bonatti I already Googled it and thank you I know what is a Loopback address.

Comment: @cloneman yes thank you this was the problem.